# Angular 2 animate sidebarmeu

Tags: angular, user-interface, animation

I want a sidebar menu that opens on a button.The sidebar menu must be animated from left slowly.The overlay sidebar should go when clicked outside of the menu or with the links in the sidebar.Can anyone help with angular 2 or higher version.What function is to be used in the @component part of angular code.?
     I also tried out with prime-ng ,but I dont want that method.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate} from 
'@angular/animations';

      @Component({ selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
 animations: [
      trigger('slideInOut', [
      state('in', style({
        transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
       })),
  state('out', style({
    transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)'
  })),
  transition('in => out', animate('400ms ease-in-out')),
  transition('out => in', animate('400ms ease-in-out'))
]),
 ]
     })
    export class AppComponent {
     title = 'app works!';
   menuState = 'out';
   toggleMenu() {
this.menuState = this.menuState === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
}
}
```

Comment: Could you include the code you tried, people won't write this code for you.

Comment: is there is any css styles for animation? @David Barker

Answer (score 0):

Angular material provides what you want with [sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview).

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/eyrbrayjmel?file=app%2Fsidenav-open-close-example.ts) is a stackblitz showing an example.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Try to avoid link only answers. Adding code examples to your answers helps to keep the answer relevant in the long run.